# Matching regex groups with Java

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

I am trying to split a line with regex by using groups, but it's not working as I expected.
I want to match for example this line:

Ex. #1: `temp name(this is the data)`

and also this:

Ex. #2: `temp name()`

I used this regex:

```
[\s]*temp[\s]+[\s]*([A-Za-z]+)[\s]*[(]\s*(.*)+[)]\s*[{]\s*
```

which means: grab anything that starts with `temp` then put in group #1 the "name" then grab whatever inside the bracket and put it in group #2.

However, group #2 is always empty.

This is my code to fetch the data:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*temp[\\s]+[\\s]*([A-Za-z]+)[\\s]*[(]\\s*(.*)+[)]\\s*");

Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher("temp name(this is the data)");
m.matches();
String name = m.group(1);
String data = m.group(2); // always empty
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't match because it requires an open curly brace at the end, but your input doesn't have one.

Ignoring that small problem, the main problem is the little `+` after your capture group `(.*)+`. The plus requires one *or more* matches of `.*` and the group returned is the *last* match of the many. The term `.*` is greedy, so it consumes everything up to the bracket. The only way to match *again* is to consume *nothing*. So the *last* match of group 2 is blank.

To fix it, remove the `+` after group 2:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*[(]\\s*(.*)[)]\\s*");
```

Note also how I removed other unnecessary characters from your regex, eg the single-character character classes - ie `[\\s]` is identical to `\s`. And `\\s+\\s*` is identical to just `\\s+`, because `+` is greedy.

I also removed the trailing curly bracket, which you can restore if your input data actually has it (your question showed input of `"temp name(this is the data)"`, which has no trailing curly bracket).

Comment: Is there a point of creating an array for ( and  ) rather than simply escaping them as single characters like so?  `\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\(\\s*(.*)\\)\\s*`

Comment: @yosefrow that's  style thing. `[(]` and `\\(` are equivalent in effect and number of characters. If the length was different, I would prefer the shorter, But since they are the same, I break the tie on readability. Personally, I find `[(]` easier to read. Further, some characters look cool when "escaped" like this, eg `[*]`, which always reminds me of [Darth Vader's Tie Fighter](http://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-vader-s-tie-fighter)

Comment: hah, I actually have the same practice of preferring brackets over escape, but I was wondering if it caused a hit to performance.

Comment: @yosefrow there would be a tiny performance hit, because the engine has to deal with a list of characters of size one rather than a single character. I just did some benchmarking, and using the character class escape costs on the order on 50 nanoseconds. In a performance critical situation (eg automated share trading) you would worry about it, but for normal commercial situations, nobody will care or notice. But fellow programmers will have to read and potentially debug your regex, so readability has real business value.

Comment: Gotta save those nano-seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*[(]\\s*(.*)[)]\\s*");
```

You had `(.*)+` which means one or more matches of `.*`. This results in nothing being captured.

Testing:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*[(]\\s*(.*)[)]\\s*");

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher("temp name(this is the data)");
        if(m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
name
this is the data
```

Answer (score 0):

`[\s]` is equivalent with `\s`

`[\s]+[\s]*` is equivalent with `\s+`

`[(]` is equivalent with `\(` (same for `[)]` and `[}]`)

This would leave your regexp as:

`\s*temp\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s*\(\s*(.*)+\)\s*\{\s*`

Assuming you actually want to match `temp name(...) {` (your regexp is looking for a `{`, while in your question you do not specify that):

`(.*)+` is your problem. You're saying: "Match any number (including 0) chatacters and put them in a capture group, repeat that at least once".

Regexp are by default greedy (= they consume as much as possible), so the capture group will first contain everything within the two brackets, then the `+` will try to match the entire group again, and will match it with `""` (the emtpy string) as this fulfils the capture group's pattern. This will elave your capture group emtpy.

What you want instead is `\s*temp\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s*\(\s*(.*)\)\s*\{\s*`

Comment: Oh Foo. Thanks @SebastianProske - fixed

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting empty groups is because you are creating multiple capture groups every time you put something between (), even if it is nested.

To make a group so it doesnt capture you can designate it as a non-capturing group by using ?: for example `(?:sometest(this is the value we want))` will return just one group while `(sometest(this is the value we want))` will return 2 groups.

For your particular regex, I have refined and simplified it, as you had capture groups you did not need.

Simple solution:

`\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\(\\s*(.*)\\)\\s*\{\\s*`

given the input:

```
Ex. #1: temp name(this is the data) {
Ex. #2: temp name() {
```

`$1 = name, $2 = data`

Pay attention to the fact that your regex contains a trailing curly brace. You can modify the regex to match without it and it will result in this:

`\\s*temp\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s*\\(\\s*(.*)\\)\\s*`

https://regex101.com/r/tD0tO0/1